# Make JTextPane adjust height to content

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jtextpane

I'm trying to get a `JTextPane` to adjust its height according to whatever content I feed it. All I can do is to set a fixed height in pixels using Dimension.

How do I make the `JTextPane` collapse/expand so it will fit to contents?

I might add that I use this in a `GridBagLayout`'ed `JPanel` that has been added to a `JScrollPane`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any direct way to do it, but this may give you some ideas:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TextPanePerfectSize extends JFrame
{
    JTextField textField;
    JTextPane textPane;

    public TextPanePerfectSize()
    {
        textField = new JTextField(20);
        textField.setText("add text");
        getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH );
        textField.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                    Document doc = textPane.getDocument();
                    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), " " + textField.getText(), null);
                    textField.setText("");
                    Dimension d = textPane.getPreferredSize();
                    Rectangle r = textPane.modelToView( textPane.getDocument().getLength() );
                    d.height = r.y + r.height;
                    textPane.setPreferredSize( d );
                    getContentPane().validate();
//                    pack();
                }
                catch(Exception e2) {}
            }
        });

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hit Enter to Add Text to Text Pane");
        getContentPane().add(label);

        JPanel south = new JPanel();
        textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setText("Some text");
        textPane.setEditable( false );
        textPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(120, 23) );

        south.add( textPane );
        getContentPane().add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new TextPanePerfectSize();
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It sort of works and then not. modelToView returns null. According to the documentation the component must have been sized for it to work. I've tried validate(), repaint(), pack() but nothing helps. Do I need to call one of these methods on some ancestor component? The JTextPane is added to a JPanel which exists inside a JPanel which again is inside a JScrollPane added to a JFrame...

Comment: That shows how to find proper height of content http://java-sl.com/tip_text_height_measuring.html

Answer (score 0):

```
JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // set layout on parent
add(tp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This works for me.