# Swing's BasicHTML.createHTMLView metrics usage

Tags: java, html, swing, size

I'm doing some graphics processing and HTML is a perfect choice for styling the displayed content. I'm trying to reuse swing's built in html support, and it works perfectly if I hard code the height passed to View.paint, but I can't figure out how to determine how tall the bounds of the rendered content would be at runtime given a specific width.

```
Graphics2D g = ...
JLabel label = new JLabel("blah blah blah...");

View view = BasicHTML.createView(label, label.getText());
int minHeight = .... // Calculation magic goes here
Rectangle htmlSize = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, minHeight);
g.setClip(htmlSize);
view.paint(g, htmlSize);
```

If I ask the JLabel direction with getPreferredSize() it doesn't consider wrapping at all. If I try using a JEditorPane it returns a larger, but fixed size rectangle.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The height can't be calculated until the width is known. When dealing with Swing components I think you need to do something like:

```
component.setSize(100, 1);
Dimension size = component.getPreferredSize();
```

Or maybe you can use the concepts present in this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126584/make-jtextpane-adjust-height-to-content):

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with this:

```java
var view = BasicHTML.createHTMLView(new JLabel(), "<html>some html</html>");
System.out.println(view.getPreferredSpan(View.X_AXIS));
System.out.println(view.getPreferredSpan(View.Y_AXIS));
```